# Does Ubuntu 12.04 equipped with Kernel 3.2.0-29 has cgroup support?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, kernel

I want to use control group (cgroup) to control and manage the computing resources of my cluster. I've done some survey work on cgroup itself, either the command line tool or the linux kernel source code. But when I was to implement a hello world program with cgroup, I found that the header file

```
#include <linux/cgroup.h>
```

is not existed in `/usr/include/linux/cgroup.h`, on my Ubuntu Server 12.04 LTS x86_64 with Linux Kernel version 3.2.0-29.

However I downloaded the kernel source file from `kernel.org`, and found that header file in the proper folder.

I also `apt-get install libcgroup-dev` and found something in `/usr/include/libcgroup/`, but those aren't what I want.

I start to wonder whether Ubuntu disabled the cgroup functionality or migrate it from the default path? How can I programming like RedHat guys do? Thank you!

Comment: Actually, I was misunderstood the concept of developing cgroup with using cgroup. If you only want to use cgroup to manage your runtime resources, just use cgroup file system; If you would like to implement your own subsystem, you should write a kernel module or recompile kernel. That's different.

Answer (score 0):

I also I have installed ubuntu 12.04 and have been working with the cgroups for some time.

Try this:

1. `apt-get install libcgroup`
2. Use `#include <libcgroup.h>` instead of `#include <linux/cgroup.h>`.